# creating window.customizedobject?

Tags: javascript

I found out that some js sources uses its own customized objects.

For example, jQuery uses `$`, and android can use javascript interface.

How can I make my customized object? what do I need to add my custom object to window object? (like `window.myObject`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not explicitly do that..

When you do, `function myFucntion(){... }` You can call it  as `window.myFunction()`

But for objects..

```
var myObject = { prop : values } //In your case, { myCustomizedObject : {} }

$.extend(window, myObject);
```

For single property you can do.. `window.myProp = "myValue";`

Note : Be careful that you do not accidentally over write values for predefined window properties. Eg: `location` etc.